# Python mysql.connect Integer in SQL Query

Tags: python, mysql

I have some python code:

```
def GetAge(tournaments):         
    cursor = cnxTurnier.cursor()
    for rows in tournaments:
        TurID = rows[0]         
        TurID = int(TurID)       
        query = ("SELECT JahrgID FROM altersklassen WHERE TurnierID = %s")

        cursor.execute(query, TurID)

        altersklassen = cursor.fetchall()
```

Im using the mysql.connector on python3.4

tournaments is the result of another SQL Query. Then I export the ID of this query and want to get additional informations (1:n relations).
MYSQL is telling me that there is an error in my SQL Sytax near to %i.
But why TurID is not replacing it?
I've got the weird feeling, that the connector re-parses the TurID into something different than MYSQl is expecting.
The SELECT is working direct in MYSQL when I replace the %i.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code an wether the TurID = int(TurID) is needed?

I've tried several things over the day and read different documentations, I can't see the issue.
Is maybe the whole idea to solve this wrong?
I want to have additional informations to another query from another table (1:n relationship).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630302/trouble-with-sql-in-python
This has solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

MySQL - or rather, the Python wrapper MySQLdb - is not expecting `%i` at all. All parameters should be `%s`.

Comment: This would explain the problem
I've changed it, but it's still telling me:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in
 SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1