# Trouble with SQL in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have this Python code:

```
def get_employees(conditions, fields):
    cursor.execute("SELECT employeeID FROM employees WHERE name=%s, budget=%s,
                   %year=%s,(some of conditions))
```

Is there any way to get `employeeID`s if I set in conditions not all parameters, etc. only name and year?

Comment: This looks a lot like psycopg2?

Comment: @Ross: The wonders of uniformity. Most database access in Python looks the same due to the standardization of the [DB-API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Answer (score 0):

If `conditions` were a dictionary, you could construct a query string:

```
def get_employees(conditions):
    query = 'select employeeid from employees'
    if conditions:
        query += ' where ' + ' and '.join(key + ' = %s' for key in conditions.keys())
    cursor.execute(query, conditions.values())
```

(I should note that here I am assuming that `conditions` does not have user-supplied keys. If there are user-supplied keys, this is definitely vulnerable to SQL injection.)

Comment: If you restrict the keys list to a known list of employee columns this removes the injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

usually it is done via dynamic sql building, like this:

```
sql = "SELECT employeeID FROM employees WHERE 1=1"; 
if condition has name
    sql += " and name='" .escape(name) . "'"
if condition has somefield
    sql += " and somefield='" .escape(somefield) . "'"
etc
execute final sql
```